# Нет доступа по NetBIOS имени через SMB

Tags: windows

Переношу шары с сервера: File (Win2008) IP 192.168.0.2 на другой сервер: NewFile (Win2019) IP 192.168.0.3

После переноса в DNS меняю A запись. Теперь File имеет тот IP 192.168.0.3

ICMP запрос нормально отрабатывает File пингуется по IP 192.168.0.3

Проверяю:

- по IP 192.168.0.3 доступ к шарам есть
- по NewFile доступ к шарам есть
- по File.office.local доступ к шарам есть
- по File пишет:

> Нет доступа к \\File. Возможно у вас нет прав на использование этого
> сетевого ресурса. Обратитесь к администратору этого сервера для
> получения соответствующих прав доступа.
>
> Конечная учетная запись указана неверно.

В чем может быть проблема?

Host файл чистый

В диспетчере учетных данных тоже ничего нет

Ошибок в событиях нет

Comment: Возможно кэш все еще хранит старый ip, как вариант попробовать очистить кэш днс

Comment: в первую очередь сделал. Сейчас я внес запись с новым IP в своем файле host. И он пингуется по новому адресу, но по NETBIOS выдает вот такую ошибку.

Comment: ну тогда очистите кэш клиента NetBIOS: `nbtstat -R`. Да не мешало бы проверить остальные сетевые настройки, например, - наличие WINS-сервера.